# Was there any pre Crisis buildup for setting up paragons?

Tags: analysis, arrowverse

In *Crisis on Infinite Earths* we heard about the paragons and as per Mar Novu:

> "Among the many misconceptions humanity holds dear is the fallacy that all beings are created equal. In truth, there are those who are greater. They are called heroes. But even among heroes, there are different echelons. The highest belongs to those known as the paragons. And they are the only hope of all creation."

But arrowverse have a habit of pre-building up such events. So I want to know is there any pre-crisis hints about these paragons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No

The first reference to Paragons in the Arrowverse was in the first episode of Season 8 of *Arrow* which featured the narration by the Monitor you referenced as I recall.